# How to get the location of an element in nightwatch.js using node.js

Tags: node.js, nightwatch.js

I am unable to locate the element in the sidemenu dashboard item. Please help me to solve this. I mention the screen shot blow,  steps for find the location.

[image]

Below is the html code:

```
<sidemenu id="sidebar-wrapper" layout="column" class="layout-column"><md-list role="list">
    <md-list-item layout="column" role="listitem" class="md-no-proxy _md layout-column">
        <a class="md-button md-ink-ripple layout-align-center-center layout-column" ng-transclude="" md-button="" aria-label="menu" href="#/dashboard" layout="column" layout-align="center center">
            <i class="material-icons silver ng-scope">view_module</i>
            <span class="ng-scope">
            Dashboard
            </span>
        </a>
    <div class="md-secondary-container"></div></md-list-item>
    <md-list-item layout="column" role="listitem" class="md-no-proxy _md layout-column">
        <a class="md-button md-ink-ripple layout-align-center-center layout-column" ng-transclude="" md-button="" aria-label="menu" href="#/projects" layout="column" layout-align="center center">
            <i class="material-icons silver ng-scope">perm_data_setting</i>
            <span class="ng-scope">
            Projects
            </span>
        <div class="md-ripple-container" style=""></div></a>
    <div class="md-secondary-container"></div></md-list-item>
    <md-list-item layout="column" role="listitem" class="md-no-proxy _md layout-column">
        <a class="md-button md-ink-ripple layout-align-center-center layout-column" ng-transclude="" md-button="" aria-label="menu" href="#/pipelines" layout="column" layout-align="center center">
            <i class="material-icons silver ng-scope">linear_scale</i>
            <span class="ng-scope">
            Pipelines
            </span>
        </a>
    <div class="md-secondary-container"></div></md-list-item>
</md-list></sidemenu>
```

I need to click the below tag **a  href="#/projects**.

**sidemenu --> md-list --> md-lidt-item [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlHYn.png) --> a  href="#/projects"**

I tried different ways but it doesn't pass the test case.

using useXpath:

```
browser.useXpath()
browser.click('//*[@id="sidebar-wrapper"]/md-list/md-list-item[1]/a[href="#/projects"]')
browser.useCss()
```

and using the getLocation:

```
browser.getLocation("#sidebar-wrapper md-list md-list-item.second a" ,function(result) {
          console.log('result', result)   // not getting anything.

        })
```

while using the above code, getting the console error like this.

```
result { status: -1,
  value: { message: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#sidebar-wrapper md-list md-
list-item.second a"}\n  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9a
a4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)' },
  errorStatus: 7,
  error: 'An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.' }
ERROR: Unable to locate element: "#sidebar-wrapper md-list md-list-item.second a" using: css selector
```

Please help me solve this. Thanks

Comment: Can you please update your post with the html (which you've posted as an image) ?

Comment: I added the html code there please look it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `#sidebar-wrapper md-list md-list-item:nth-child(2)`

nth-child(n) is a better approach to get the nth element.

:first-child to get the first one

:last-child to get the last one

:nth-child(n) to get the nth one

Comment: I tried like this could you please check once where i did the mistake 
browser.getLocation("#sidebar-wrapper md-list md-list-item:nth-child(2)" ,function(result) {
  console.log('result', result);
})

Comment: do click on this selector directly